# PDF rendering within application with iText jar

Tags: android

I am able to create annotation in a pdf file using iText jar but I am not able to read those annotations again in app using iText.

Answer (score 0):

do the annotation you create with your app display if the pdf is opened with Adobe Reader
for Android? You could try getting the pdf you manipulated with your app onto a pc and inspect
the syntax of the annotations using iText-Rups.

Possible reasons your annotations are not showing,

not associated with a page (pdf page)
might not be drawn within the coords as defined by the /Rect.

However, if you get them opened with the iText-Rups tools you will get a better
idea on what is missing or is misplaced in their dictionaries and always follow the
PDF Standard, it's all there.

Regards,

Thomas